# E: The repository 'http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty Release' no longer has a Release file

Tags: software-installation, tlp

I did a fresh install on my Asus x201e the other day to 17.04. I just tried to install the battery saving app, TLP, but when I did, I got this response:

```
    Reading package lists... 
Done Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  guile-2.0-libs libgc1c2 libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 libmailutils5 libntlm0
  libunwind8 linux-tools-4.10.0-21 linux-tools-4.10.0-21-generic
  linux-tools-virtual mailutils mailutils-common postfix postfix-sqlite
  smartmontools tlp-rdw
Suggested packages:
  mailutils-mh mailutils-doc procmail postfix-mysql postfix-pgsql postfix-ldap
  postfix-pcre postfix-lmdb sasl2-bin dovecot-common postfix-cdb postfix-doc
  gsmartcontrol smart-notifier tp-smapi-dkms acpi-call-dkms
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  guile-2.0-libs libgc1c2 libgsasl7 libkyotocabinet16v5 libmailutils5 libntlm0
  libunwind8 linux-tools-4.10.0-21 linux-tools-4.10.0-21-generic
  linux-tools-virtual mailutils mailutils-common postfix postfix-sqlite
  smartmontools tlp tlp-rdw
0 to upgrade, 17 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
Need to get 5,302 kB/6,335 kB of archives.
After this operation, 30.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libgc1c2 amd64 1:7.4.2-8ubuntu1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:2 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 guile-2.0-libs amd64 2.0.13+1-4
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:3 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libntlm0 amd64 1.4-8
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:4 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libgsasl7 amd64 1.8.0-8ubuntu3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:5 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libkyotocabinet16v5 amd64 1.2.76-4.2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Ign:6 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 mailutils-common all 1:3.1.1-1
Err:7 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 libmailutils5 amd64 1:3.1.1-1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:8 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 libunwind8 amd64 1.1-4.1ubuntu2
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:9 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 postfix-sqlite amd64 3.1.4-4
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:10 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 postfix amd64 3.1.4-4
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:11 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 mailutils amd64 1:3.1.1-1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:12 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 smartmontools amd64 6.5+svn4324-1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Ign:13 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 tlp all 0.9-3
Ign:14 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 tlp-rdw all 0.9-3
Err:6 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe i386 mailutils-common all 1:3.1.1-1
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:13 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe i386 tlp all 0.9-3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
Err:14 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe i386 tlp-rdw all 0.9-3
  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgc/libgc1c2_7.4.2-8ubuntu1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/guile-2.0/guile-2.0-libs_2.0.13+1-4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/libn/libntlm/libntlm0_1.4-8_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/gsasl/libgsasl7_1.8.0-8ubuntu3_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/k/kyotocabinet/libkyotocabinet16v5_1.2.76-4.2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mailutils/mailutils-common_3.1.1-1_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mailutils/libmailutils5_3.1.1-1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libu/libunwind/libunwind8_1.1-4.1ubuntu2_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postfix/postfix-sqlite_3.1.4-4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/postfix/postfix_3.1.4-4_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/m/mailutils/mailutils_3.1.1-1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/smartmontools/smartmontools_6.5+svn4324-1_amd64.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tlp/tlp_0.9-3_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/tlp/tlp-rdw_0.9-3_all.deb  403  Forbidden [IP: 202.158.214.106 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Any ideas what I should do? Because currently, it looks like I can't install ANYTHING.

Comment: This is trying to install an incredible amount of stuff including an email system. Please edit your question to clean up the formatting and show the actual commands you entered.

Comment: Could you please edit your question to include the  *full, verbatim* output of `sudo apt-get update`? Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a broken mirror.  Can you try using a different region mirror for a while?

Answer (score 2):

AARNet had some minor issues with the server farm which drives that mirror.  They report this has been permanently fixed; please try again now.

If you ever find a problem with your usual Ubuntu mirror, you can always select another from the list at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors.

Comment: Note that Paul Gear here is a member of the Canonical IS team and is one of a group of people responsible for keeping an eye on the regional mirrors among other things.  He speaks from absolutely authoritative information that I can back up from the #ubuntu-mirrors IRC channel on Freenode where I reported this issue with a link here.  (This was an evil mirror problem, as I had surmised)

Comment: Yep, and I can confirm that the issue with the mirror now seems to have been resolved. Thanks to all for your help.